# Extract data according to three different columns

Tags: excel

I want to extract `MIPS` from following table according to the `Hour`, `JOB` and `Date`:

```
ENG JOB LPAR    Hour    Date              MIPS      
Z #1    ABC DSYS    7   8/13/2015   40.94618333 
Z #1    ABC DSYS    6   8/13/2015   41.94618333
Z #1    DEF DSYS    11  8/13/2015   0.229885    0.69
Z #1    GHJ DSYS    8   8/14/2015   21.51257167
```

I don't know if VLOOKUP or INDEX and MATCH can be used here?

Comment: If hour, job & date are unique, then just use a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5). If they are not unique, the matching rows would total up but you would also have to decide which matching row you would want for a multiple criteria lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array formula (Google: excel array formula multiple lookup). However if you can add an "Index column", the following way could be fine.

1. convert your data to a table called Inputs
2. add a first column IndexCol = [@JOB]&[@Hour]&[@Date]
3. put your parameters e.g. in following cells:

   - Job C21
   - Hour C22
   - Date C23
4. extract your MIP with following formula : =VLOOKUP(C21&C22&C23,Inputs,7,0)

[image]